# Why does my apps get more native memory on Vendor/App?

Tags: android, performance, dalvik, heap-memory, ashmem

I am seeing different behavior on my memory usage ( dalvik and native also other ) when I install my app in /vendor/app rather than installing with package manager into /data/data.
Does android treat these apps differently and pre-allocate more memory to the processes it finds in vendor ?

Also my native heap in one of my processes that deals with database increases sharply when it is installed on vendor/app compared to /data/data which is almost flat lined.

Can someone help me with this issue ?

Comment: I would look at your map files under /proc/[pid number] while it is running in each mode as it is possible that forcing the installation as you are doing causes some problem - speculating wildly, perhaps you don't have a aligned zip and so the contents must be duplicated in memory or something like that.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your response, I have clean up stage before installing for both that clears the vendor,data and dalvik-cache.

Comment: Also I tried native snapshot with DDMS and I can see libsqlite.so is the major cause of the increase, I've checked my database implementation and ensured all cursors are freed , my database object lives on for the life of application as it is being used constantly. However the footprint on native seems unusual.